# AWS Lambda: The function is idle

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am studying Lambdas of my project and I've seen that one of them is idle. In the top of dashboard page I see block with text:

> The function __ is idle. To reactivate your function, choose Restore.

I slightly confused of it because this function is very similar to others which isn't marked as idle but as well haven't been launched for couple of months.
Since I haven't find answers in AWS documentation i'd appreciate somebody to explain me what difference between functions in idle state and not, and how/why function becomes Idle?

Comment: What happens if you try to invoke it?

Comment: i've already restore it, i'll try invoke if i find another idle one.

Comment: Is this function associated with a VPC, while the other unused functions are not?  What's the state of the others?

Comment: Yes, this function is associated with VPC, while other unused functions are not. Others don't have some specific state (or at least I can't observe it), their dashboard seems usual, without any difference from that ones that executes frequently

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is related to VPC, please check this doc.

> If your functions aren't active for a long period of time, Lambda
> reclaims its network interfaces, and the functions become Idle. To
> reactivate an idle function, invoke it. This invocation fails, and the
> function enters a Pending state again until a network interface is
> available.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html

Comment: This is not isolated to VPC Lambdas. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/functions-states.html

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a Cloudwatch event, I would suggest using Provisioned Concurrency to keep a lambda(s) warm.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/aws-lambda-announces-provisioned-concurrency/

Comment: Provisioned concurrency is the most proper answer, but it can get expensive! My workplace has many stages, and I run 5GB+ Lambdas. I costed it out at $800/month to have a provisioned concurrency of 1 for our dev stages which should otherwise sit mostly idle

Answer (score 2):

You will need to invoke functions often using cloudwatch events regularly if you want your Lambda functions to stay alive & warm. Otherwise they will cool down as @Traycho Ivanov says.

Setup up cloudwatch events to invoke the Lambdas you need alive every so often, but how often is a bit debated it's not clear how AWS manages this and this could easily be changed into the future that your event is not frequent enough, or maybe it is too frequent costing you a couple more cents than you would otherwise want!

Comment: can you provide some specifics or link to a "debate" for how frequent?

Comment: Really depends on your requirements. Run it every minute if you want until somebody complains about $$$. If no body complains 1 minute is your answer ( ;

Comment: You really don't need 1 minute. AWS states "several weeks" (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/tracking-the-state-of-lambda-functions/), so you'd be safe with daily. If they went any shorter, they'd annoy even more people than they already do with this feature

Comment: I've been avoiding dealing with this issue for nearly a year now, and can tell you that "several weeks" is spot on - I've never had functions go idle in under a week, and they seem to go there consistently within 4 weeks. Note that only "expensive" functions go idle - ones that have huge container images or have VPC network interfaces etc